# How to create a Excel sheet at first tab using OLEDB.ACE provider with C#.net

Tags: c#-4.0, excel-2007, oledb

I am able to create a new sheet inside an Excel file with sheet name as "Usage-08" by writing a query like

```
strQuery = "CREATE TABLE [Usage-08] ( Client TEXT,Division TEXT,Site TEXT)";
cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And the new sheet is creating at the end of already existing sheets i.e. Sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,Usage-08

I need to create a sheet at the first position.

Note: currently I am using `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`
and I should not use `Interop.dll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" provider it is not possible if we use Interop dll reference we can customize.